# Why the voltage is zero?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

The question is asking to find ID1 and ID2 of the two ideal diodes in the circuit below:

[image]

I solved it as follows:

[image]

The correct solution is as follows:

[image]

I would like to know where is my mistake. Also, why did he assume that the voltage at the anodes to be zero? why not 3 or 2 volts? How did he arrive to zero?

The source:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I know the question numbers are different,however, they are the most relevant to the question asked.

Comment: Where did the original problem come from?

Comment: Just have to say, ***THIS*** is how you ask for help with a homework problem! Kudos for showing your work and your initial attempt. +1 for that.

Comment: As Andy says, it would be good to know where this "correct" solution comes from. Meanwhile, please don't "fix" your answer.

Comment: Questions to help you : What is the voltage over an ideal diode in forward bias? When you have that in mind, what is the voltage at the common junction of the diodes?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the ground symbol (grown is 0 volt isn’t it?)

Comment: Can you explain to us why do you think the D1 diode will be OFF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, with a little effort, the solution that is given as correct is wrong. Just analyse the current through D1 with D2 disconnected: -

[image]

The maximum current that can flow through D1 (assuming it is ideal with zero volt drop i.e. conditions that maximize current flow), is 6 volts / 43 kΩ = 0.1395 mA or 139.5 μA.

Given that the so-called correct solution is 409 μA, it is clearly miles off.

**You cannot trust the so-called "correct solution".**

> *I would like to know where is my mistake.*

I would say (given the recent history of you posting questions that supposedly have "correct answer") that your mistake is in trusting these sites or books.

> *Also, why did he assume that the voltage at the anodes to be zero? why
> not 3 or 2 volts? How did he arrive to zero?*

I've established that the "correct solution" source is faulty so there's no point trying to wonder what they did.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118319/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-why-the-voltage-is-zero).